# Google API geocode in Excel VBA returns blank

Tags: excel, vba, api, geocoding, api-key

I created an Excel VBA function for geocoding address. It worked last year.

Google started a new billing process and the code does not work.

> input:address
>   output: Lat, Long

```
Function getGoogleMapsGeocode(sAddr As String) As String

Dim xhrRequest As XMLHTTP60
Dim sQuery As String
Dim domResponse As DOMDocument60
Dim ixnStatus As IXMLDOMNode
Dim ixnLat As IXMLDOMNode
Dim ixnLng As IXMLDOMNode

getGoogleMapsGeocode = ""

Set xhrRequest = New XMLHTTP60
sQuery = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address="
sQuery = sQuery & Replace(sAddr, " ", "+") & "&key=MY-API-KEY"

xhrRequest.Open "GET", sQuery, False
xhrRequest.send

Set domResponse = New DOMDocument60
domResponse.LoadXML xhrRequest.responseText
Set ixnStatus = domResponse.SelectSingleNode("//status")

If (ixnStatus.Text <> "OK") Then
    Exit Function
End If

Set ixnLat = domResponse.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat")
Set ixnLng = domResponse.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng")

getGoogleMapsGeocode = ixnLat.Text & ", " & ixnLng.Text

End Function
```

I got it to work by changing one old server key but that brought another question.

I recently registered two API key which do not work. However, the old server key works. What is the difference between API key and server key?

[image]

Comment: "code does not work any more." is not a very useful description of your exact problem.  What happens when you run this ?

Comment: Your code works as it should here, with a proper address and api-key.  Possibly you have not properly set up your api key with google; or your address is messed up.  But, as @TimWilliams writes, your problem description is not useful for troubleshooting.

Comment: Have you tried Postman to see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

[Geocoding VBA Excel 2010](https://pastebin.com/7cHanMH9)

Thanks to my brother Edu for your help!

Option Explicit

Function GetCoordinates(Address As String) As String

```
'This function returns the latitude and longitude of a given address using the Google Geocoding API.
```

'The function uses the "simplest" form of Google Geocoding API (sending only the address parameter),
   'so, optional parameters such as bounds, language, region and components are NOT used.
   'In case of multiple results (for example two cities sharing the same name), the function
   'returns the FIRST OCCURRENCE, so be careful in the input address (tip: use the city name and the
   'postal code if they are available).

```
'NOTE: As Google points out, the use of the Google Geocoding API is subject to a limit of 40,000
```

'requests per month, so be careful not to exceed this limit. For more info check:
   'https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet

```
'In order to use this function you must enable the XML, v3.0 library from VBA editor:
```

'Go to Tools -> References -> check the Microsoft XML, v3.0.
   'If you don't have the v3.0 use any other version of it (e.g. v6.0).

```
'2018 Update: In order to use this function you will now need a valid API key.
```

'Check the next link that guides you on how to acquire a free API key:
   'https://www.myengineeringworld.net/2018/02/how-to-get-free-google-api-key.html

```
'2018 Update 2 (July): The EncodeURL function was added to avoid problems with special characters.
```

'This is a common problem with addresses that are from Greece, Serbia, Germany and other countries.

```
'Written By:    Christos Samaras
```

'Date:          12/06/2014
   'Last Updated:  09/08/2018
   'E-mail:        xristos.samaras@gmail.com
   'Site:          https://www.myengineeringworld.net
   '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
'Declaring the necessary variables.
```

'The first 2 variables using 30 at the end, corresponding to the "Microsoft XML, v3.0" library
   'in VBA (msxml3.dll). If you use any other version of it (e.g. v6.0), then declare these variables
   'as XMLHTTP60 and DOMDocument60 respectively.
   Dim ApiKey          As String
    Dim Request         As New XMLHTTP30
    Dim Results         As New DOMDocument30
    Dim StatusNode      As IXMLDOMNode, LatitudeNode As IXMLDOMNode, LongitudeNode As IXMLDOMNode

```
'Set your API key in this variable. Check this link for more info:
```

'https://www.myengineeringworld.net/2018/02/how-to-get-free-google-api-key.html
   '****************************************************************************************************************
   ApiKey = "Your API Key goes here!"
    'example: ApiKey = "lxI800lklv3sdf3v5F6........."